# extra a value from a file in bash script

Tags: awk, sed

i have this file content in my sample file "haproxy-monitoring.conf"

```
[[inputs.haproxy]]
servers = ["http://localhost:31330/haproxy?stats" ]
```

Can you please help me, how I can extract just the port number '31330' from the file haproxy-monitoring.conf in a bash script.

Answer (score 2):

with `sed`

```
$ sed -rn '/servers/s/.*:([0-9]+).*/\1/p' file
```

or similarly with `awk`

```
$ awk '/servers/{print gensub(/.*:([0-9]+).*/,"\\1",1)}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'[:/]' '{print $5}' file

31330
```

Answer (score 0):

Or something like

```
grep -Eo '[0-9]+' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Questions that state what the output should be without explaining why it should be that leave you open to all sorts of answers unrelated to what you really are trying to do. idk if this is what you want or not since you haven't told us:

```
$ tr -cd '0-9' < file
31330
```